# How long does it take for the addition of www on the website to be indexed on Google?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, web-development, optimization, asp.net

If I search my website in google, it show like this :

[image]

The url that appears in the google search result is without `www`. I want to bring up `www` there. So I was setting in my web config. When I access `https://example.com`, it will redirect to `https://www.example.com` and now it has worked

Then I search on google, there is still no `www`. Does it take a long time for the `www` to appear in Google's search results? How long?

Comment: I am curious why you would want to force the www. part of a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think anyone can give you a time frame as to when your pages will be indexed by Google. There are a few things you can do to facilitate the process, such as going in to [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/) and adding the www version of your domain. There you can submit a sitemap as well as request your pages be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Just did this, and it took 5 days. I didn't submit an XML Sitemap from Google Search Console, which supposedly could help.